# How do refer to an element at the 'accuracy' row from sklearn.metrics.classification_report?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

How can I properly refer to one specific element at the 'accuracy' row of the classification report?

```
tuned_pdf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_rf_tuned,target_names=target_names,digits=4,output_dict=True)).transpose()

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred_rf_tuned,target_names=target_names,digits=4))
tuned_pdf
tuned_pdf.replace(tuned_pdf.iloc[2,0], 'X')
tuned_pdf.replace(tuned_pdf.iloc[2,1], 'Y')
tuned_pdf.replace(tuned_pdf.iloc[2,2], 'Z')
```

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Stay     0.9896    0.9980    0.9938      7999
    Left     0.9895    0.9473    0.9679      1593

accuracy                          0.9896      9592   
macro avg     0.9895    0.9726    0.9809      9592 
weighted avg  0.9896    0.9896    0.9895      9592
```

[image]